# Windows laptop for programming, make music and editing videos

Tags: development, windows, music, video-editing

This is my first question on this StackExchange site, so please let me know how I can improve it.

I am interested in a Windows laptop (I need to program with it - including [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio)), but besides this I want to use it also to make music (ReasonStudios, here the [requirements](https://help.reasonstudios.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002215674-What-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-Reason-11-), and being able to use with a synth keyboard), and performant enough for making timelapse video (including GoPro, not necessarily 4K).

So the requirements are:

-8 GB RAM

-at least 1TB storage

-Windows 10

-Intel Core i7

-Monitor with at least 1280 x 768 resolution

-I am Not a big expert about the graphic board, so I cannot really say whatare the best requirements for video editing

For the needed characteristics I saw a gaming laptop (OMEN by [HP 15-DH0039NL](https://support.hp.com/it-it/document/c06468461)).

Is it a good one? Would you suggest some other laptop?
My budget is <1700€$ (but of course depends on the value)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you prefer a 13 inches (more compact) or a more classical 15 inches screen?

Comment: I would prefer a 15 inches screen

Comment: Are you a student? (just asking because several vendors have discount for students)

Comment: No, i am not student

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For HP I would recommend:

- The best fit at $1850: [HP Spectre x360 15 EB0065NR](https://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-spectre-x360-laptop-15-eb0065nr)
- Same idea, at $1450: [HP Spectre x360 15 DF1040NR](https://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-spectre-x360-15-df1040nr)

If you can afford it, I would definitely go for the first one since it has everything you're looking for. The second one has a graphics card not as powerful as the first one, and "only" 512GB of SSD (note that you could add a very good external hard disk drive and stay below $1700 total).